# Travis-CI build - PhantomJS error preventing QUnit tests from running

Tags: github, phantomjs, qunit, travis-ci

I have a repository with a simple js function and a QUnit test. I have attempted to integrate it with Travis-CI using a grunt task. Everything works fine locally but PhantomJS throws an error during the build process preventing my tests from running.

Build:
https://travis-ci.org/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox/builds/40909225

Repo:
https://github.com/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox

```
//.travis.yaml

language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.11"
before_install: npm install -g grunt-cli
install: npm install

// Gruntfile.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: '<json:package.json>',
    qunit: {
      src: ['test/**/*.html']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');

  grunt.registerTask('test', ['qunit']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'qunit');

};
```

Error:
Testing test/index.html 
PhantomJS threw an error:ERROR

> > /home/travis/build/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 4: /home/travis/build/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string 0 [ '/home/travis/build/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 4: /home/travis/build/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string' ]
> >     Warning: PhantomJS exited unexpectedly with exit code 2. Use --force to continue.
> >     Aborted due to warnings.
> >     The command "npm test" exited with 0.
> >     Done. Your build exited with 0.

Comment: Strange, not sure exactly what could cause it, but since you're not using your package settings in the grunt file, how about trying to remove the `pkg: '<json:package.json>',` line?

Comment: Thanks for your response jakerella. Unfortunately removing 'pkg' didn't work. I still get the PhantomJS error: https://travis-ci.org/DaveKingsnorth/ciSandbox/builds/41019254

Comment: Why did you commit the `node_modules` directory? By using `npm install` this would be created on the CI server. Maybe that interferes with the checked-in code.

Comment: I think this was the case. Thanks for your response, it took me a long time to get to that conclusion on my own!